# can we create/ access History of Document viewers

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set, version-history, 2016

Is there any way to create or see the history of documents viewers in sharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can Configure `Site Collection Audit Settings` as the following

- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site collection audit settings

[image]

- select first option . opening or downloading , viewing content

[image]

Then Try to use Audit Report

- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Audit log reports > **Content Viweing**

[image]